# PHP Encontrar diretório informando parte do nome do diretório

Tags: php, diretório, sistema-de-arquivos

Olá!

Já possuo um protótipo de aplicação funcionando em PHP, onde acesso fotos de determinado diretório. Porém, os diretórios não ficaram muito amigáveis, por exemplo:

```
2016/783/01/2016-07-26-00001
```

Para ficar um pouco mais amigável, seria interessante que o terceiro e quarto elementos que são respectivamente categoria e evento, pudessem ter um nome à direita.

Ficando assim:

```
2016/783/01-relatorios/2016-07-26-00001-relatorio semanal 21
```

O que eu gostaria era acessar essa mesma pasta porém ignorando totalmente os textos do caminho, onde basicamente o código ignoraria os textos.

Nunca precisei fazer isso, estou lendo tudo a respeito do Filesystem e correlatos, mas ainda não achei uma solução!

Estas pastas estão todas linkadas com banco de dados, em tese não há necessidade alguma de fazer essa inclusão dos textos no caminho, porém, estou pensando em implementar isso, porque num futuro creio que alguém que for mexer no Backup vai acabar me causando problemas porque não está entendendo nada.

Obrigadão!

Comment: Renomear os arquivos seria custoso para você nesse caso? Eu pensaria nessa possibilidade. A "mágica" que você quer fazer, consigo imaginar algo como `glob` ou `FilterIterator` combinado com `RegexIterator`.

Comment: Oi Wallace! Na verdade, o sistema já nomeia os arquivos. As pessoas selecionam 1 ou mais arquivos e fazem o upload. Neste processo, o arquivo enviado ganha um nome específico e vai pra seu diretório específico. O que eu pretendo é informar apenas os dados numéricos que estão no banco e estes abrirem o diretório que contém dados de texto. Como eu expliquei acima, eu apenas estou querendo evitar problemas futuros. Porque já está funcionando redondinho. Já estou pesquisando com o blob e vou ver tb com FilterIteration. Obrigado, abraço!

Comment: Os aquivos estão com este padrão de nome: 2016-07-26-783-00001-DJI_0754.jpg, mas a questão é que estão separados por diretórios. Estruturamos a arvore de diretórios como ANO > OBRA da Empresa > Categoria > Evento, algumas obras da empresa duram anos, e cada obra tem um número, etc. Complexo!!!! kkkkk

Answer (score 0):

Isso deve servir para o que você quer:

```
<?php
$dir = "2016/783/01-relatorios/2016-07-26-00001-relatorio semanal 21";

$peaces = explode("/", $dir);

foreach ($peaces as $idx => $peace) {
    if (preg_match("/-\D+/", $peace, $match)) {
        $new_peace = substr($peace, 0, strpos($peace, $match[0]));
        $peaces[$idx] = $new_peace;
    }
}

$dir = implode("/", $peaces);
echo $dir;
?>
```

Estamos buscando um padrão pelo caractere (-) seguido de não dígitos.

A saída será:

```
2016/783/01/2016-07-26-00001
```